# Help with overloading the limits of CPU/RAM issue in a resseler account with wp sites

Tags: errors, hosting, cdn, shared-hosting

The server that I am on has these characteristics:

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5506 @ 2.13GHz/24GB ddr3
- CloudLinux Server release 5.7 64 bit/litespeed webserver
- And overall are 800 clients (in whois.domaintools.com that I am looking right now the Shared IP Address of the server that I am is the "Reverse IP: 1,195 websites use this address.")

And the limits are 1gb of memory and 25 concurrent connections

In the reseller account that I have I created two accounts:

1. WordPress Multisite with 3 sites in under contraction/coming soon message with 2 gb ram and 30 concurrent connections (I don't know why, I am waiting for an answer from my host provider). [The last 7 days from Resource Usage Details](http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/3504/1stmultisiteresourceusa.jpg)
2. A WordPress eZine blog with 4000-6000 monthly unique visitors/150-200 a day visits with 2 gb ram and 20 concurrent connections (I don't know why, I am waiting for an anwser from my host provider). [The last 7 days from Resource Usage Details](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/6983/2dezineresourceusagedet.jpg)

The eZine blog has 25 Active Plugins:

- Admin Locale
- AdRotate
- All in One SEO Pack - Pro Version
- Calendar Posts
- CloudFlare
- Contact Form 7
- Easy Mashable Social Bar
- FeedBurner FeedSmith
- Google Analytics for WordPress
- Google XML Sitemaps
- JW Player Plugin for WordPress
- NextGEN Gallery
- Really Simple CAPTCHA
- registration-login
- TentBlogger SEO Categories
- Top 10
- Twitter Embed
- W3 Total Cache
- WP-DownloadManager
- WP-Optimize
- WP-PageNavi
- WP-reCAPTCHA
- WP-UserOnline
- WP Smush.it
- WP Smush.it NextGEN Gallery Integration

My problem is when am going to apply or save the setting of a plug in or when am going to publish or save as a draft a post I get same message:

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily busy, try again later! Powered By LiteSpeed Web Server
> LiteSpeed Technologies is not responsible for administration and contents of this web site!

Also it takes a lot of time for my site load. It doesn't load the virtual editor of the post. And the only thing that my hosting provider suggests to optimize my site(But, I already use plug ins (CloudFlare,W3 Total Cache, WP Smush.it & WP Smush.it NextGEN Gallery Integrationor) in order to optimize my site) to move to a Cloud server.

What do you think about that? Should I move to a Cloud server or use CDN to my current reseller account or in a new host provider?

Also, does the problem really starts from me or my hosting has done a lot of overselling? Please suggest me anything that will be useful for my problem and if it's necessary to give you some information(That I might have forgot to mention) to help you understand.

Comment: I don't see anything in particular wrong with your setup as you have described it, you might want to try asking this question over at webmasters.stackexchange, they might have some better insight to offer.

Comment: I would be contacting my server provider.

Comment: Close vote as off topic. To the extent that this question is **WordPress** specific, it is far too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is the fact that you're on shared hosting.  The fact that 1,195 websites are using the same IP address is a dead giveaway.  You're likely running into resource limits with your hosting provider.

Second is a misconception of what caching does to optimize a site.  Caching helps clean up and optimize load times *on the front-end of your site.*  None of the caching solutions you've talked about will be turned on when you're logged in to your site ... when you are editing pages, posts, and comments you're running in an uncached mode and using the maximum resources available.

If you're running this many sites on your system (it looks like you have 1 live site and 3 in-development sites) you'd be best served looking for a dedicated hosting solution.  Either a real server or a VPS.

There are some [potential hosting providers](http://wordpress.org/hosting/) listed on WordPress.org.  Take a look at their offerings and consider upgrading your hosting.

Comment: they give my a dedicated ip address, and W3 Total Cache have this options on Page Cache: Don't cache pages for logged in users
Users that have signed in to WordPress (e.g. administrators) will never view cached pages if enabled. so i deactivated this or is not a good idea?

Comment: Whether you have a dedicated IP or not, *there are 1,195 websites running on your box.*  And that flag to cache front-end pages for logged in users will *still* only affect the front-end.  It will not do anything with WP admin pages - and you're seeing your 503 error when you try to do things with WP admin pages.

Comment: Ok I will follow your advices and if I get stuck anywhere I will re-edit the post so that you can help me better, but I think that is too early to go in dedicated hosting is too expensive to move a site that 4000 to 6000 unique visitors per month.